# Plot with pgfplots and its intersections with the x-axis

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to plot a simple second-degree polynomial using pgfplots and show its intersections with the x-axis.

I am using this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
axis x line=center,
axis y line=none,
xmin=-0.75,xmax=1.5,ymin=-2, ymax=0.3,
xtick={-0.25,...,+1},
xticklabels={$-\frac{1}{4}$, 1},
x tick label style={anchor=north},
]
\addplot[blue,mark=none]
plot[domain=-0.75:1.5,samples=40]
(\x,{(4*\x*\x -3*\x -1});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The polynomial is `4x^2 -3x -1`, with roots -1/4 an 1.

However, I get this wrong plot:

[image: plot]

I have two questions:

1. what am I missing?
2. is there any way to have the x tick labels
   ABOVE the axis instead of below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have `xtick={-0.25,...,+1}`, meaning that you get ticks spaced by `1`, starting at `-0.25`, ending at `1`. In other words, one tick at `-0.25`, and one tick at `0.75`. Remove the `...`.
2. `x tick label style={above=3pt}`. I'd think that `anchor=north` is the default.

Note also that you're mixing `pgfplots` and TikZ syntax. The `plot` keyword (from TikZ) is usually used as `\draw plot ...`. I'd use

```
\addplot[blue,mark=none,domain=-0.75:1.5,samples=40] {4*x^2 -3*x - 1};
```

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
axis x line=center,
axis y line=none,
xmin=-0.75,xmax=1.5,ymin=-2, ymax=0.3,
xtick={-0.25,1},
xticklabels={$-\frac{1}{4}$, 1},
x tick label style={above=3pt},
]
\addplot[blue,mark=none,domain=-0.75:1.5,samples=40] {4*x^2 -3*x - 1};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: even if with some years of delay, thank you :-)